# Why typescript doesn't infer type of "this" in prototype function?

Tags: typescript

So for the sake of this experiment (I'm not actually doing this in my application, relax) let's say I have something like this

```
declare global {
  interface String {
    capitalize(): string
  }
}

String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase().concat(this.slice(1));
}
```

Now, to be honest I expected that in the function capitalize, "this" would be inferred as a string, but it doesn't.

I need to use the typescript trick of sending a fake this to the function in order for it to work:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(this: string) {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase().concat(this.slice(1));
}
```

Am I naive/oblivious for thinking it should because of prototype, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you're just hitting one of the pragmatic limits of how hard the TypeScript compiler is going to work to infer things. Say they added inference for that. Would we then expect it for `Object.assign(String.prototype, { a() { /*...*/ }, b() { /*...*/ });`? Or `function addMethod(ctor: {prototype: Record<string, Function>}, name: string, method: Function) { ctor.prototype[name] = method; } addMethod(String, "a", function() { /*...*/ });`? You get the idea. :-) There are **lots** of things TS *could* do with unlimited CPU time, but lots of things it doesn't do because it doesn't have that.

Comment: [I can't reproduce this issue](https://tsplay.dev/we08aW); could you ensure that you've got a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE so that others can demonstrate the problem for themselves?  If there are specific config requirements to reproduce, you should isolate them and then tell us what they are.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Oh you're right.. maybe it's just Visual Studio Code then that doesn't infer it.
You wrote it exactly as I did but in VSC he doesn't know "this" is a string.